# Retain attributes when using gather from tidyr (attributes are not identical)

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame that needs to be split into two tables to satisfy Codd's 3rd normal form. In a simple case, the original data frame looks something like this:

```
library(lubridate)
> (df <- data.frame(hh_id = 1:2,
                   income = c(55000, 94000),
                   bday_01 = ymd(c(20150309, 19890211)),
                   bday_02 = ymd(c(19850911, 20000815)),
                   gender_01 = factor(c("M", "F")),
                   gender_02 = factor(c("F", "F"))))

    hh_id income    bday_01    bday_02 gender_01 gender_02
  1     1  55000 2015-03-09 1985-09-11         M         F
  2     2  94000 1989-02-11 2000-08-15         F         F
```

When I use the gather function, it warns that the attributes are not identical and loses the factor for gender and the lubridate for bday (or other attributes in the real-world example). Is there a nice tidyr solution to avoid the loss of each column's data type?

```
library(tidyr)
> (person <- df %>% 
      select(hh_id, bday_01:gender_02) %>% 
      gather(key, value, -hh_id) %>%
      separate(key, c("key", "per_num"), sep = "_") %>%
      spread(key, value))

     hh_id per_num       bday gender
   1     1      01 1425859200      M
   2     1      02  495244800      F
   3     2      01  603158400      F
   4     2      02  966297600      F

   Warning message:
   attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped

> lapply(person, class)

  $hh_id
  [1] "integer"

  $per_num
  [1] "character"

  $bday
  [1] "character"

  $gender
  [1] "character"
```

I can imagine a way to do it by gathering each set of variables with the same data type separately and then joining all the tables, but there must be a more elegant solution that I'm missing.

Comment: I don't think there is an elegant solution currently :(  For this case, I _think_ gather might need to make a list-column so that the attributes won't be lost. But I think that will be quite slow, and might be confusing to people.

Comment: @hadley Ah I see. Yes I was writing a function that returns a list result and it was terribly slow. I'm in the middle of finding a better solution for that right now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could just convert your dates to character then convert them back to dates at the end:

```
(person <- df %>% 
      select(hh_id, bday_01:gender_02) %>% 
      mutate_each(funs(as.character), contains('bday')) %>%
      gather(key, value, -hh_id) %>%
      separate(key, c("key", "per_num"), sep = "_") %>%
      spread(key, value) %>%
      mutate(bday=ymd(bday)))

  hh_id per_num       bday gender
1     1      01 2015-03-09      M
2     1      02 1985-09-11      F
3     2      01 1989-02-11      F
4     2      02 2000-08-15      F
```

Alternatively, if you use `Date` instead of `POSIXct`, you could do something like this:

```
(person <- df %>% 
      select(hh_id, bday_01:gender_02) %>% 
      gather(per_num1, gender, contains('gender'), convert=TRUE) %>%
      gather(per_num2, bday, contains('bday'), convert=TRUE) %>%
      mutate(bday=as.Date(bday)) %>%
      mutate_each(funs(str_extract(., '\\d+')), per_num1, per_num2) %>%
      filter(per_num1 == per_num2) %>%
      rename(per_num=per_num1) %>%
      select(-per_num2))
```

**Edit**

The warning you're seeing:

```
Warning: attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped
```

arises from gathering the gender columns, which are factors and have different level vectors (see `str(df)`). If you were to convert the gender columns to character or if you were to synchronize their levels with something like,

```
df <- mutate(df, gender_02 = factor(gender_02, levels=levels(gender_01)))
```

then you will see that the warning goes away when you execute

```
person <- df %>% 
        select(hh_id, bday_01:gender_02) %>% 
        gather(key, value, contains('gender'))
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. When I have time I'm going to look at the source code and see why @hadley has chosen to require the same attributes. There must be a good reason.

Comment: @josiekre I've updated my answer to explain why you're getting that warning.

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to like my [base solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954585/tidyrs-gather-with-nas#comment46162893_28954585). Let me tempt you once more

```
(df <- data.frame(hh_id = 1:2,
                  income = c(55000, 94000),
                  bday_01 = ymd(c(20150309, 19890211)),
                  bday_02 = ymd(c(19850911, 20000815)),
                  gender_01 = factor(c("M", "F")),
                  gender_02 = factor(c("F", "F"))))


reshape(df, idvar = 'hh_id', varying = list(3:4, 5:6), direction = 'long',
        v.names = c('bday','gender'), timevar = 'per_num')

#     hh_id income    per_num       bday gender
# 1.1     1  55000          1 2015-03-09      M
# 2.1     2  94000          1 1989-02-11      F
# 1.2     1  55000          2 1985-09-11      F
# 2.2     2  94000          2 2000-08-15      F
```

Comment: This is a workable solution for sure. I'm going to hold out to see if a tidyr solution is available as I need to use regular expressions to select the varying columns. Unfortunately the data source doesn't always have the columns in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

With *tidyr 1.0.0* it can be done as follows :

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyr)
  library(lubridate)
})
df <- data.frame(hh_id = 1:2,
                 income = c(55000, 94000),
                 bday_01 = ymd(c(20150309, 19890211)),
                 bday_02 = ymd(c(19850911, 20000815)),
                 gender_01 = factor(c("M", "F")),
                 gender_02 = factor(c("F", "F")))

pivot_longer(df, -(1:2), names_to = c(".value","per_num"),names_sep = "_" )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   hh_id income per_num bday       gender
#>   <int>  <dbl> <chr>   <date>     <fct> 
#> 1     1  55000 01      2015-03-09 M     
#> 2     1  55000 02      1985-09-11 F     
#> 3     2  94000 01      1989-02-11 F     
#> 4     2  94000 02      2000-08-15 F
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>