# remove duplicates from values in the rows

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a df with dimension 58000*900 which contains replicates in row values, I want to traverse through every row and remove them. An example will make it more clear.

```
df
IDs Name    col1    col2    col3
123 AB.C    1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3 0,0,0,0,0   5,5,5,5,5
234 CD-E    2,2,2,2,2   0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3 1,1,1,1,1
568 GHJ 123456      123456              123456
345 FGH 9,9,9,9,9   54,54,54,54,54  0,0,0,0,0
```

Apparently every value is replicated 5 times and in some cases their is a problem that there is no `.` or `,` separating the values.
What I want is drop those lines which does not contain either `.` or `,` and for the rest remove the duplicate values. So, the output will be:

```
IDs Name    col1    col2    col3
123 AB.C    1.3 0   5
234 CD-E    2   0.3 1
345 FGH 9   54  0

dput(df)
structure(list(IDs = c(123L, 234L, 568L, 345L), Name = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("ABC", "CDE", "FGH", "GHJ"), class = "factor"), 
    col1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("123456", 
    "1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3", "2,2,2,2,2", "9,9,9,9,9"), class = "factor"), 
    col2 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("0,0,0,0,0", "0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3", 
    "123456", "54,54,54,54,54"), class = "factor"), col3 = structure(c(4L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("0,0,0,0,0", "1,1,1,1,1", "123456", 
    "5,5,5,5,5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("IDs", "Name", 
"col1", "col2", "col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: can you please `dput()` your `df`?

Comment: To clarify, you want to drop rows that don't have `,` or `.` and then remove replicates from the rows.

Comment: @lmo: Yes, you are right

Comment: @mtoto: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we restructure your data in a long format using `gather()`, then we `filter()` for `value` with no `,` using `grepl()`. We then split the string in `value` into a list using `strsplit()` and make each element of the list it's own row using `unnest()`. We remove duplicated rows using `distinct()` and `spread()` back the `key` and `values` to columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -(IDs:Name)) %>%
  filter(grepl(",", value)) %>%
  mutate(value = strsplit(value, ",")) %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  distinct %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#
#    IDs   Name  col1  col2  col3
#  (int) (fctr) (chr) (chr) (chr)
#1   123   AB.C   1.3     0     5
#2   234   CD-E     2   0.3     1
#3   345    FGH     9    54     0
```

---

Another idea would be to use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`:

```
df %>%
  cSplit(., c("col1", "col2", "col3"), direction = "long", sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(!any(is.na(.))) %>%
  distinct
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data table [3 x 5]
#Groups: Name
#
#    IDs   Name  col1  col2  col3
#  (int) (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (int)
#1   123   AB.C   1.3   0.0     5
#2   234   CD-E   2.0   0.3     1
#3   345    FGH   9.0  54.0     0
```

Comment: It works, but gives the `Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped`. I searched this error (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972386/retain-attributes-when-using-gather-from-tidyr-attributes-are-not-identical) but could not understand the reason !!

Comment: You can safely ignore this warning, it just coerces each factor to character and drops their attributes when creating the `value` column in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method that works for your sample data:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="IDs Name    col1    col2    col3
 123 ABC 1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.3 0,0,0,0,0   5,5,5,5,5
                  234 CDE 2,2,2,2,2   0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3 1,1,1,1,1
                  568 GHJ 123456      123456              123456
                  345 FGH 9,9,9,9,9   54,54,54,54,54  0,0,0,0,0")

# drop rows with no comma or dot
df <- df[-grep("[,.]", df$col1, invert=T),]

df[,grep("^col", names(df))] <- sapply(df[,grep("^col", names(df))], 
                                       function(i) gsub("^([0-9.]+),.*", "\\1", i))
```

This returns

```
  IDs Name   col1   col2   col3
1 123  ABC    1.3      0      5
2 234  CDE      2    0.3      1
3 568  GHJ 123456 123456 123456
4 345  FGH      9     54      0
```

We use regular expression functions `grep` and `gsub` to select the correct columns and to remove the part of each string that comes after a comma.

Answer (score 1):

The long `apply` way in base R:

```
as.data.frame( apply( df, c(1,2), gsub, pattern="(\\d*[.]*\\d*),.*", replacement="\\1") )
```

Which gives:

```
  IDs Name   col1   col2   col3
1 123  ABC    1.3      0      5
2 234  CDE      2    0.3      1
3 568  GHJ 123456 123456 123456
4 345  FGH      9     54      0
```

The idea is to keep only the first element before the first comma for each item

Drawback (?) it keeps the rows with no decimal values.