# Use R to count values in a number of different columns

Tags: r, count, find-occurrences

I have a dataset of patents, where I have recorded 1) the month and year associated with a patent renewal and 2) whether the patent holder chose to pay the patent fee or let the patent lapse. So

```
patentid        fee1date         fee1paid    fee2date    fee2paid
1               May 2010       True        May 2013    False 
2               May 2010       True        April 2014  True
```

What I want to do is develop a count of the number of renewals by month and by year, as well as the number of abandoned patents, as follows:

```
date      renewed              lapsed
May 2010  2                   0
```

How might I count the data that I have now? Thank you!

EDIT: The key point is to aggregate these across different columns. The issue that I am running into now is that when I try using the count library, it treats 2 renewals in May 2010 as two separate values.

Comment: Minor advice - try to avoid capitals and spaces in your column names

Comment: And - how do you get to `No Patents Renewed 11` from your example data frame? This looks like magic to me. Please explain!

Comment: Upper case is ok, but spaces cause trouble

Comment: I agree, but upper case can be pain for typing. :)

Comment: Sorry, it was a dummy value that I included :P

Comment: how u realize that patent abandoned in 2010 ? you just know that abandon time is between 2010 and 2013 !

Comment: Sorry SaMi GiMiX, I don't quite understand your comment. Most patent offices release information about filing fees online, so it is possible to work backwards to see whether a patent has been renewed or not.

Comment: It seems that `lapsed` should be 1 because the `fee2paid` for line 1 is FALSE. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, because I am looking at the number of renewal statistics by month. Because there is no lapse in May 2010, the count for that month is 0.

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)      

data %>% gather(year,value, -Patent.ID) %>% 
         separate('year',c('Fee','N','Act')) %>% 
          spread(Act,value) %>% 
          unite(Fee, Fee,N, sep = '.') %>% 
          group_by(Date) %>% 
          summarise(R=sum(Paid=='True'), NotR=sum(Paid=='False'))

     # A tibble: 3 x 3
  Date           R  NotR
  <chr>      <int> <int>
1 April 2014     1     0
2 May 2010       2     0
3 May 2013       0     1
```

## Data

```
data <- read.table(text="
               'Patent ID'      'Fee 1 Date'   'Fee 1 Paid'    'Fee 2 Date'   'Fee 2 Paid'
               1               'May 2010'       True        'May 2013'    False 
               2               'May 2010'       True        'April 2014'  True

               ",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Hi A. Suliman, thanks for the help! I've tried your approach but unfortunately I get the following error message: `In addition: Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972386/retain-attributes-when-using-gather-from-tidyr-attributes-are-not-identical

Comment: Eventually I got there, I used the plyr count and aggregate function to add each of the columns together. Thanks for your help though!